# How to use an Android phone or iPad as a virtual microphone and/or video input?

Tags: sound, android, webcam, microphone

I want to use motion tracking software like VSeeFace and a voice converter like Lyrebird, but I don't have a webcam or a microphone. Buying them seems like a waste of money to me because I thought that I could use my phone or iPad as wireless input devices in some way, but I couldn't figure out how to do that.

I've been searching for many days. There are 2 methods that achieved something, but they're not what I wanted:

1. Using OBSNinja with OBS Browser plugin I could use my phone as a webcam, but it wasn't considered as an input at all by the system. I don't want to see myself or hear myself. I want the program to recognize that there is a webcam input, so it can track my face or body.
2. Using IP Camera with VLC network protocol I got a result like the previous one. It was able to get the sound and reproduce it as a system sound, but the computer didn't recognize any microphone connected, so Lyrebird didn't work with it.

I've read about other methods like WO Mic, but I thought it would be better at this point to ask someone with more knowledge than me about this issue.

Comment: I was able to achieve the video input part using droidcam, maybe I'll be able to solve the audio input with the same method, but I'm still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Droidcam worked both for video and audio. For the audio there is a problem where I have to use this (pacmd load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:Loopback,1,0) in the terminal each time after I reboot or shut down my PC.

Answer (score 0):

I found this entire ALSA PulseAudio integration issue with DroidCam a real headache. So I crafted a solution for myself.

You can find it here and with a very long winded explanation of the problems:

https://github.com/aidyw/droidcam-snd-manager
Hope someone finds this useful.